# Where to get prepaid stored value cards capable of having higher limits (e.g. $10,000)?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, debit-card

When I was drafting consumer protection guidelines for stored value cards, I heard there were cards that stored balances as high as $10,000.

Yet, when I go to convenience stores, I only see stored value cards and gift cards with a max of $500 that can be preloaded on them.

Where do you get the ones that are capable of having higher limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Western Union prepaid cards](https://www.wuprepaid.com/wuprepaid/public/compare.do?PROMOID=mastercard&pid=MCtix_0711) have a limit of $10K maximum load, as an example. You cannot load more than $950 per transaction or per 24 hours, i.e.: You need to spend more than 10 days loading it to reach the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that you can't usually load more than $1k in store.  Some GPR (General Purpose Reloadable) cards like Amex Serve, PayPower, and many GreenDot cards allow you to direct deposit your paycheck to them.  These cards have limits more in the $5k-10k range for total balance and monthly spend.

The non-reloadable cards I've seen in stores max out at $500.

Some of the card program managers like Omnicard have custom options for companies that want to hand out cards (for promotions, etc) that may take larger amount of money, though I'm not familiar with them.